# Magento Onepage checkout horizontal Design

Tags: checkout, theme, onepage-checkout

Hi 'm working on the magento responsive theme using bootstrap.

In my onepage Checkout page, i need to customize that as horizontal listing.

> I have followed some tutorial. But in those tutorial they have use
>   **fixed height** for that.I don't want to use like that.

So i have tried in `app\design\frontend\default\default\template\checkout\onepage.phtml` as follow

```
<div class="row-fluid steps">
<?php $i=0; foreach($this->getSteps() as $_stepId => $_stepInfo): ?>
<?php if (!$this->getChild($_stepId) || !$this->getChild($_stepId)->isShow()): continue; endif; $i++ ?>
    <div id="opc-<?php echo $_stepId ?>1" class="span3 section<?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['allow'])?' allow':'' ?><?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['complete'])?' saved':'' ?>">
        <div class="step-title">
            <b class="number"><?php echo $i ?></b>
            <?php echo $_stepInfo['label'] ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>

<ul class="unstyled opc" id="checkoutSteps">
<?php $i=0; foreach($this->getSteps() as $_stepId => $_stepInfo): ?>
<?php if (!$this->getChild($_stepId) || !$this->getChild($_stepId)->isShow()): continue; endif; $i++ ?>
    <li id="opc-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="section<?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['allow'])?' allow':'' ?><?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['complete'])?' saved':'' ?>">
        <div class="step-title">
        </div>
        <ul id="checkout-step-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="step a-item unstyled cart-list" style="display:none;">
            <li>
                <h3> <?php echo $_stepInfo['label'] ?></h3>
            </li>
            <li class="row-fluid"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_stepId) ?></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

> This code display 'll display as i want. But the Accordion was not
>   working.

Can some one explain to do this.

I don't want to install extension for this.

Answer (score 1):

I've played around with a horizontal checkout a while ago and you're free to use the code. It's [on Github](https://github.com/sandermangel/rkcheckout) and except for a helper class it's all templating and some CSS. If you have specific issues or questions let me know, I'll try and explain.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Its shows **Error** like `Module "Redkiwi_Rkcheckout" requires module "Redkiwi_Rkextbase"`.
In your `app/etc/module/Redkiwi_Rkcheckout.xml` 
`<depends>
    <Redkiwi_Rkextbase/>
   </depends>` what should i replace for that

Comment: Ahh sorry, It's not really necessary. I've updated the code on Git

Comment: Thanks,it does not show active steps.And one more thing could you make the Steps are at the top of the page after the page title

Comment: This was a hobby project a while back and I'm not developing on it any more so any changes I'm afraid you will have to do yourself. If you run into a specific issue I'll be glad to assist

Comment: thanks for your help.I have try that but the accrodation is not working for me. Do you have any idea about this.Please help me

Comment: It's probably some javascript error if the accordion is not working. Please check your console for that

Comment: i'll try that. if i have any clarification Please assist me

Comment: Did you manage to result your issue?

Comment: Your github link is not working now can you please update answer.